# displaying front viewcontroller of SWReveal with toggle botton

Tags: swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I have an application where I am using SWreveal and I also have a bottomSheet in the front View controller. I have to open the view controller programmatically for the bottom sheet to work and the issue I have now is if I have a code like this

```
let storyboard = R.storyboard.baseSB()

            let swVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: SWRevealViewController.className) as! SWRevealViewController

            swVC.loadView()

            let homeVC = swVC.frontViewController as! HomeVC

            homeVC.mode = AppMode.go
            let bottomSheetVC = BottomSheetVC(contentViewController: swVC, drawerViewController: UIViewController())
            bottomSheetVC.drawerCornerRadius = 0
            bottomSheetVC.initialDrawerPosition = .closed
            bottomSheetVC.shadowRadius = 0
            bottomSheetVC.shadowOpacity = 0

            homeVC.bottomDrawer = bottomSheetVC
            bottomSheetVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve

            self?.present(bottomSheetVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

everything works with the side drawer and i can toggle the view controllers but the bottomSheet does not work, passing it in like this, makes the bottoSheet work but if I click on the toggle button the app crashes

```
let storyboard = R.storyboard.baseSB()

let swVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: SWRevealViewController.className) as! SWRevealViewController

swVC.loadView()
storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: HomeVC.className) as! HomeVC

let homeVC = swVC.frontViewController as! HomeVC

homeVC.mode = AppMode.go
let bottomSheetVC = BottomSheetVC(contentViewController: homeVC, drawerViewController: UIViewController())
bottomSheetVC.drawerCornerRadius = 0
bottomSheetVC.initialDrawerPosition = .closed
bottomSheetVC.shadowRadius = 0
bottomSheetVC.shadowOpacity = 0

homeVC.bottomDrawer = bottomSheetVC
bottomSheetVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve

self?.present(bottomSheetVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

how can I fix this so that the application works without a crash when I toggle the side view controller button

Comment: Where does it crash and what does the crash error say?

Comment: Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x10463266c)